# How can I write a pdf with iText with Syntax highlighting?

Tags: java, syntax, pdf-generation, itext

Is there any way to write a PDF in iText with syntax highlighting?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting

Any Plugins, libs etc.? I would like to add syntax highlighting to my .java, .xml, .php files when I am writing them into a PDF(a single PDF, by the way).

EDIT: The project which I am writing(that generates the PDF) is written in java, so I need java-compatible libraries

Comment: Check out GeSHi (**Ge**neric **S**yntax **Hi**ghlighting) to convert your code to HTML; then use iText's XML Worker to convert that HTML to PDF. Show us what you've tried and what is blocking you, now that you know which tools to use.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked much with iText lib but you can refer the link below where you can set a color for a chunk which might help you.

[Set background color of chunk/text](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=14)

Something like this:-

```
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
Chunk id = new Chunk("Text", font);
// with a background color
id.setBackground(BaseColor.BLACK, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, 1.5f);
```